# Recursive query and change target table depending on result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Supposing I have a query like:

```
SELECT type_person FROM tbl_event WHERE id_animal = 1;
```

this gives me the type of person and the target table to join (In this case this will return 'worker') from other tables to get whole data of an event, to make a join now I know that I must do a join on 'worker table' like:

```
SELECT  a.*,b.*,z.*
FROM    tbl_event a
        left JOIN tbl_worker b
            ON a.type_person = b.type_person
        left JOIN tbl_animal z
            ON   z.id_animal = a.id_animal 
        WHERE z.id_animal = 1;
```

Is there a way to change the part left JOIN tbl_worker b by something like:

```
SELECT  a.*,b.*,z.*
FROM    tbl_event a
        left JOIN (SELECT type_person FROM tbl_event WHERE id_animal = 1)
            ON a.type_person = b.type_person
        left JOIN tbl_animal z
            ON   z.id_animal = a.id_animal 
        WHERE z.id_animal = 1;
```

[here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13bd1/9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you need to do something like:

```
SELECT  a.*,b.*,z.*
FROM    tbl_event a
        left JOIN (SELECT type_person FROM tbl_event WHERE id_animal = 1) as b
            ON a.type_person = b.type_person
        left JOIN tbl_animal z
            ON   z.id_animal = a.id_animal 
        WHERE z.id_animal = 1;
```

Basically you're missing the alias (`b` in this case)

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13bd1/11)

Answer (score 1):

of course you can . you mean like that

```
 SELECT  a.*,b.*,z.*
 FROM    tbl_event a
    left JOIN (SELECT type_person FROM tbl_event WHERE id_animal = 1) b
        ON a.type_person = b.type_person
    left JOIN tbl_animal z
        ON   z.id_animal = a.id_animal 
  where z.id_animal = 1;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13bd1/14)

in your query you just forgot to make `AS b`